Create 0-1 columns based on another dataframe with start and end dates for events
Context, I have a dataframe with a time index and values associated. And another dataframe (an "events dataframe") in which each row is an event with its start and end times and type.
Question: what is the simplest and fastest/most efficient way to create a new column in my dataframe, for each row in my events dataframe.
Here is some sample data and my current approach.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
df_idx = pd.date_range(start='2024-03-04', end='2024-03-10', freq='h')
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'placeholder': np.random.randint(1000,size=len(df_idx))}, index=df_idx)

df_events = pd.DataFrame([
    ['football', pd.Timestamp('2024-03-04 15:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2024-03-04 16:59:59')]
    ,['concert', pd.Timestamp('2024-03-05 19:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2024-03-05 21:59:59')]
    , ['football', pd.Timestamp('2024-03-07 18:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2024-03-07 19:59:59')]
    , ['football', pd.Timestamp('2024-03-08 18:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2024-03-08 19:59:59')]
    , ['public_event', pd.Timestamp('2024-03-09 16:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2024-03-09 23:59:59')]
]
    , columns=['type','start','end']
            )

#This is my current approach

#Get the unique events types
events = df_events['type'].unique()

#Iterate over the df_events rows per event, and create a new column in df
for event in events:
    df[event]=0
    for idx, row in df_events[df_events['type']==event].iterrows():
        df.loc[(df.index>=row['start'])&(df.index<=row['end']),event]=1

df.head(5)


The expected output would be a dataframe with the original time index and the placeholder column, as well as 3 other columns called "football", "concert" and public events with 0, and 1 where the time index is between the start and end of the respective events.
Something like this:

Is there a better way to do this?
Note: of course, my dataframes are much larger in reality and I get warning because of the iterrows approach.

Do you mind to add the expected output?

kindly use a reproducible dataset. I have added an np.random.seed(0) to your dataset to ensure the same data everytime.

You can use this:
ranges = pd.Series(
    [
        pd.date_range(start, end, freq="H")
        for start, end in zip(df_events["start"], df_events["end"])
    ]
)

types = (
    ranges.explode()
    .to_frame(name="range")
    .join(df_events["type"])
    .set_index("range")["type"]
)

df = (
    df.join(pd.get_dummies(types))
    .fillna(0)
    .astype(int)
    .groupby(level=0)
    .max()
)

                     placeholder  concert  football  public_event
2024-03-04 00:00:00          684        0         0             0
2024-03-04 01:00:00          559        0         0             0
2024-03-04 02:00:00          629        0         0             0
2024-03-04 03:00:00          192        0         0             0
2024-03-04 04:00:00          835        0         0             0
...                          ...      ...       ...           ...
2024-03-09 20:00:00          554        0         0             1
2024-03-09 21:00:00          973        0         0             1
2024-03-09 22:00:00          368        0         0             1
2024-03-09 23:00:00          999        0         0             1
2024-03-10 00:00:00          917        0         0             0

[145 rows x 4 columns]

print(df[df["concert"].eq(1) | df["football"].eq(1) | df["public_event"].eq(1)]) will output:
                     placeholder  concert  football  public_event
2024-03-04 15:00:00          472        0         1             0
2024-03-04 16:00:00          600        0         1             0
2024-03-05 19:00:00          755        1         0             0
2024-03-05 20:00:00          797        1         0             0
2024-03-05 21:00:00          659        1         0             0
2024-03-07 18:00:00          779        0         1             0
2024-03-07 19:00:00          430        0         1             0
2024-03-08 18:00:00          660        0         1             0
2024-03-08 19:00:00          227        0         1             0
2024-03-09 16:00:00          816        0         0             1
2024-03-09 17:00:00          861        0         0             1
2024-03-09 18:00:00          387        0         0             1
2024-03-09 19:00:00          610        0         0             1
2024-03-09 20:00:00          554        0         0             1
2024-03-09 21:00:00          973        0         0             1
2024-03-09 22:00:00          368        0         0             1
2024-03-09 23:00:00          999        0         0             1


You're right, there was a typo, I corrected the sample data

@I've updated the answer with the result using the corrected sample data. The solution is still the same.

I like your answer because it does not use other imports than the ones I used. There’s still the apply and I wonder if it still works if there are events from the type happening at the same time (overlapping) but it is definitely a good path

@Adn You have valid concerns. I've updated my answer with a different way of constructing the date ranges without apply, which should be much faster. Also, I've added a groupby on the index aggregating with max at the end to deal with overlapping events.

I know the OP sample data was constructed with freq='h', but do we know that we can assume that the real data has regularly spaced timestamps, just like the sample data?  If not, then this approach won't work.  It relies on you being able to exactly match the timestamps of df_idx using pd.date_range()

for me it'll work because in the real data I'll use resample('h').sum() to have a monotonic index with hourly intervals
@e-motta I don't understand the utility of prefix="", prefix_sep=""; I tried with and without and it does not seem to change the result

@Adn It's not needed. At some point when I was working on the solution types had 2 columns range and type, so I used prefix="", prefix_sep="" to remove the original column name from the column names in the result of get_dummies. I later realized I could .set_index("range")["type"] and do a join instead of a merge... Long story short, now types is a series, so the column names are not added to the result of get_dummies, and prefix="", prefix_sep="" is not needed and has no effect. I just forgot to remove it.

I think your original approach is close, but could be cleaned up and made more efficient with just one for-loop:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
df_idx = pd.date_range(start='2024-03-04', end='2024-03-10', freq='h')
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'placeholder': np.random.randint(1000,size=len(df_idx))}, index=df_idx)

events = [
    ['football',     '2024-03-04 15:00:00', '2024-03-04 16:59:59'],
    ['concert',      '2024-03-05 19:00:00', '2024-03-05 21:59:59'],
    ['football',     '2024-03-07 18:00:00', '2024-03-07 19:59:59'],
    ['football',     '2024-03-08 18:00:00', '2024-03-08 19:59:59'],
    ['public_event', '2024-03-09 16:00:00', '2024-03-09 23:59:59']
]
df_events = pd.DataFrame(events, columns=['type', 'start', 'end'])
df_events = df_events.astype({'start': 'datetime64[ns]', 'end': 'datetime64[ns]'})

event_types = sorted(df_events['type'].unique())
df[event_types] = 0
for event_type, start, end in df_events.itertuples(index=False):
    df.loc[start:end, event_type] = 1

print(df.loc[df[event_types].any(axis=1)])

                     placeholder  concert  football  public_event
2024-03-04 15:00:00          472        0         1             0
2024-03-04 16:00:00          600        0         1             0
2024-03-05 19:00:00          755        1         0             0
2024-03-05 20:00:00          797        1         0             0
2024-03-05 21:00:00          659        1         0             0
2024-03-07 18:00:00          779        0         1             0
2024-03-07 19:00:00          430        0         1             0
2024-03-08 18:00:00          660        0         1             0
2024-03-08 19:00:00          227        0         1             0
2024-03-09 16:00:00          816        0         0             1
2024-03-09 17:00:00          861        0         0             1
2024-03-09 18:00:00          387        0         0             1
2024-03-09 19:00:00          610        0         0             1
2024-03-09 20:00:00          554        0         0             1
2024-03-09 21:00:00          973        0         0             1
2024-03-09 22:00:00          368        0         0             1
2024-03-09 23:00:00          999        0         0             1

